# How to call an image in drawable folder from xml file?

Tags: android, xml

I wanna make a different button for "spacebar" in my custom skin smartkeyboard for android.

[image: here]

is my custom skin. I can put the images in drawable folder. I wanna make my spacebar button look different for the normal condition and also pressed condition. I've already put the image file in drawable folder. and here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<skin version="1.0" name="Bu">
  <background>
       <image>skin.png</image>
  </background>
  <key-background>
    <normal>normal.9.png</normal>
    <pressed>pressed.9.png</pressed>
  </key-background>
  <mod-key-background>
    <normal>normal.9.png</normal>
    <pressed>pressed.9.png</pressed>
    <normal-off>normal.9.png</normal-off>
    <pressed-off>pressed.9.png</pressed-off>
    <normal-on>mod_on.9.png</normal-on>
    <pressed-on>mod_on_pressed.9.png</pressed-on>
  </mod-key-background>
  <symbols>
    <delete>backspace.png</delete>
    <return>return.png</return>
    <search>search.png</search>
    <shift>caps.png</shift>
    <shift-locked>caps.png</shift-locked>
    <space>spacebar.png</space>
    <mic>micro.png</mic>
  </symbols>
  <colors>
    <label bold="true">#FFFFFFFF</label>
    <alt-label>#FFFFFFFF</alt-label>
    <mod-label>#FFFFFFFF</mod-label>
  </colors>
</skin>
```

so, what code name should I add, to call the button from drawable folder for spacebar. and where do I have to put it?

EDIT : the `<space>spacebar.png</space>` works for the icon not the button. the `<symbol>` works for the icons, and the `<key-background>` works for the button.

Comment: What does `<space>spacebar.png</space>` do? Isn't this what you need?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the <space>spacebar.png</space> works for the icon not the button. the <symbol> works for the icons, and the <key-background> works for the button.